# IIS6, VBS & XMLHTTP: Execute Access Denied

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, directory-security

I've got a VBS file that is pulling XML from our website.  It going to run on our local server once it is finished.

Te problem I'm having is that when I run the file on my workstation (Running IIS6 on XP SP3), I get the error:

"Execute Access Denied: This Virtual Directory does not allow objects to be executed."

I'm opening the file from my desktop, so I understand there's a security parameter that needs to be changed to allow executables to have access to XMLHTTP. How do I fix this?

```
Function Get_XML(api_url)
    Dim objHTTP, RespText, TempRespText
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    objHTTP.open "Get", api_url, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    objHTTP.send

    RespText = objHTTP.ResponseText

    'Get_XML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    'Get_XML.async = False
    'Get_XML.loadXML RespText

'For testing:
    Get_XML = RespText

    Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  Apparently the version of VBScript I'm running won't allow the MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to run.  Not sure if it's the actual version or a security update.  So I changed:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

To:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

And it runs perfectly.